# Are "const" arrays resident in memory if a binary is replaced during execution?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, security

I have a C program with the following code defining an array at the beginning of the program:

```
const uint8_t test_data[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};
```

I have this program running, with the data being iterated through by another method in my program.

If I were to replace the binary of the running program with another that had different array values:

```
const uint8_t test_data[] = {
    0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11,
};
```

(eg. it was another compiled executable of the exact same structure, aside from the array values being different)

Would the program continue to read the previous binary's values since they're already loaded into memory, or would it read them from the new binary that has modified values?

The machine this will be running on is a custom Linux build that doesn't have any protections against overwriting running binaries. I attempted to test this on my Windows development machine, but Windows will stop you from overwriting the binary while it's running, making it impossible to test.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that the values in `test_data` will change while the program is running? If so, merely declaring `test_data` as const will allow the compiler to optimize away many redundant reads to the array. If you declare it as `const volatile test_data[]`, then it's clear to the compiler the values may not be written to by the program, but that they may also change at any time and need to be re-read continuously.

Comment: The point was actually to prevent this from happening, but thank you for the information! I was just making sure that even if the binary was replaced during runtime (perhaps by a malicious user), it wouldn't interfere with the currently executing program.

Comment: @PadBrogrammer You cannot simply _replace binaries_ which are currently executed. Refer to languages like Erlang to achieve such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, No. All major operating systems load programs into memory and then execute them. This is referred to as the "Loader" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)

That does not mean all hope is lost. Theres a few routes to changing these values. For one, there is IPC. IPC commonly uses named pipes, shared memory, or sockets as a way of communicating. On Windows, you can use OpenProcess() and WriteProcessMemory to change the values at a runtime. I dont know the Linux equivalents off the top of my head but I know its possible. If its only a few bytes, WriteProcessMemory is your best bet IMO.

Edit: If you are concerned about security, there are many ways you can modify nearly any process at a runtime. Things like Code-caves,DLL-injection,WriteProcessMemory(), and Manual Mapping are some of the first techniques that come to mind. On windows, some software will implement obRegisterCallback hooks to strip access rights away when handles are made to another process.

Comment: While this is true of the data in programs, most modern operating systems load the code simply by memory-mapping the executable. Theoretically they could do the same for `const` data, but I think you're correct that they don't.

Comment: Note that this is exactly why you van update Linux machines while using it, while Windows requires a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have to separate hex files.

One for code and one for data. The file for code can be continuously running and refresh the data from the second hex file at periodic intervals (say 100 ms or 1 sec)

The second hex file should be at a fixed location in the code flash so that the main code can consistently access the data.

To change the data at run-time, is a more intricate challenge. If you directly try to flash using a programmer, I believe the execution of the main program will stop.

One option is to use a bootloader to get the constant data over a network and then flash it at run time.

There are many caveats to this and the whole system will have to be carefully designed, but it can be done in this way.